# SonarQube for MSBuild YAML definition error

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, yaml, azure-devops

I am trying to add the Sonar analysis task into a Yaml build definition for VSTS.

I've generated the Yaml from an existing build which isn't Yaml and it generated the following:

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubeScannerMsBuildBegin@3
  inputs:
    projectKey: 'mykey'
    projectName: 'projectName'
    projectVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    connectedServiceName: 'SonarQube'
```

However I get an instant build failure:

> Step input connectedServiceName references endpoint SonarQube which could not be found. The service endpoint does not exist or has not been authorized for use.

The service name is correct and works for the non-yaml version. So I am not sure how to resolve. When I look through https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ for examples of the Yaml synax I can't see Sonar at all. So I did wonder if this taks is not actually supported

Updated:

I was using v3 of the task so I have updated to v4 the yaml now the following:

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'ab0ef446-6a80-xxxx-xxxx-xx...'
    projectKey: 'mykey'
    projectName: 'myname'
    projectVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

However I still receive the following error:

> Step input SonarQube references endpoint ab0ef446-6a80-xxxx-xxxx-xx... which could not be found. The service endpoint does not exist or has not been authorized for use

Comment: Which version of the task are you using? We released v4 recently, and the name of the parameter to set the endpoint has changed.

Comment: Same issue here and I'm on v4.

`
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'xxxxxxxx'
    projectKey: 'xxxx'
    projectName: 'xxxx'
    projectVersion: 'xxxx'
    extraProperties: 'sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/TestResults/**/*.coveragexml'
`
@JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: From the dropdown, the SonarQube parameter is set to the name of the service, but should it be the Guid instead? @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: @DevOverflow source for the task is here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts

Comment: Have updated to v4 and using resourceid, (updated original question with details) but still generating error

Comment: I'm still having issues, as well.  Maybe this might help: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1301

Comment: @DevOverflow solved it by renaming my build file to `.vsts-ci.yml`.

Comment: @DevOverflow Any update on this issue, did nagytech's workaround work?

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply, was away. Once it was on master it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem come from the fact you are experimenting on a branch (not on master).
Seems that authorization to get endpoint is depending on the fact your yaml is on the master branch.

See [*YAML getting started - Endpoints*](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/3d39fca3cac2bf54c16600e0a3b9e7972d4c5ef3/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-endpoints.md) and [*YAML getting started - Authorization*](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/3d39fca3cac2bf54c16600e0a3b9e7972d4c5ef3/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-authz.md)

Update: previous links are now part of outdated documentation. Latest documentation is [*Service Connections - Use a service connection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#use-a-service-connection) and doesn't mention any constraint. But I found [this comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2304#issuecomment-438941133) that still implies that endpoint should be declared in the default branch:

> Also make sure the changes you are making are being pushed to the
>   default branch (or change your default branch). This way the service
>   endpoint that you have create is authorized.